# How to set a fallback value for bound variables in blazor application?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, blazor

Coming from WPF development, I'm playing around with ASP.NET and Blazor and I have a bit of trouble understanding the following:
I want to bind for example a CSS class value to a property of a code-behind class.

```
@inherits TextGenerator
<style>
    .mycssclass
    {
        opacity: @TextOpacity;
        transition: opacity 2s;
    }
</style>
<div class="modal-dialog-centered">
    <h1>@Text</h1>
</div>
```

This is what the code-behind class looks like:

```
public class TextGenerator : ComponentBase
{
    public event Func<Task> OnPropertyChanged;

    private string _text;
    public string Text 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged.Invoke();

        }
    }

    private float _textOpacity;
    public float TextOpacity
    {
        get
        {
            return _textOpacity;
        }
        set
        {
            _textOpacity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged.Invoke();

        }
    }

    protected async Task StartTextSlideShow()
    {
        Text = "";
        TextOpacity = 1.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Text = "Test #" + i.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged += PropertyChange;
        _ = StartTextSlideShow();
    }

    public async Task PropertyChange()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

My question is the following: How can I set an initial or fallback value for the opacity? In this case for example I want the opacity to be initialized to `0`, so that when I set it to `1.0f` in `StartTextSlideShow()` the text will fade in.

Comment: I've removed my first answer as it was incorrect.  Question : Do you want to start the "SlideShow" and fade in on the page initialization?  If not how do you trigger it?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I'll check everything out tomorrow and answer after testing

Comment: As for the fade - in exactly: I basically want the page to load, then text fade in. As a final result I had something in mind which looks like the text one sees during a initial Windows 10 setup ("This might take a few minutes...", etc.). Additionally I have a video in the background which should slowly fade in. As mentioned, this is just me playing around to get into the web stuff.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a similar answer that picks up on your slideshow and fade in for each pseudo picture.

The Razor Code:

```
@page "/Text"
<style>
    .mycssclass
    {
        opacity: @_opacity;
        transition: opacity @_transition;
    }
</style>

<div class="modal-dialog-centered mycssclass @_cssClass  p-5">
    <h1 class="">@_text</h1>
</div>
```

And the code behind:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Timers;

namespace StackOverflow.Server.Pages
{
    public partial class TextGenerator : ComponentBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        private string _text = "Slide Show Starting";
        private decimal _opacity = 0m;
        private string _transition = "0s";
        private int _counter = 0;

        private int _pictureCount = 5;

        private string _cssClass = "bg-white text-white-500 border border-secondary";

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            _opacity = 1m;
            _transition = "2s";
            _timer.Interval = 4000;
            _timer.AutoReset = true;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public async void TimerElapsed(Object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _cssClass = "bg-primary text-white";
            _counter++;
            _opacity = 0m;
            _transition = "0s";
            await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            await Task.Delay(1);
            _text = $"Picture {_counter}";
            _opacity = 1m;
            _transition = "2s";
            await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            if (_counter >= _pictureCount)
                _timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```